# Eclipselink History Policy not working with MySQL Generated id's

Tags: mysql, eclipselink

I have a simple entity object and history policy

```
@Entity
@Customizer(MyHistoryPolicy.class)
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    ... accessor methods
}


public class MyHistoryPolicy implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
        String historyTableName = descriptor.getTableName() + "_history";
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addHistoryTableName(historyTableName);
        policy.addStartFieldName("start_date");
        policy.addEndFieldName("end_date");
        descriptor.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

Inserting a new object works fine.  Updating an object results in the id being set to zero.  I see the following debug logs from Eclipselink

```
UPDATE employee SET name = ? WHERE (id = ?)
    bind => [test name, 2]
UPDATE employee_history SET end_date = ? WHERE ((end_date IS NULL) AND (id = ?))
    bind => [2017-09-27 17:45:25.316, 2]
INSERT INTO employee_history (id, name, start_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [2, test name, 2017-09-27 17:45:25.316]
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Note the "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" after the history table insert.  The history table does not have a generated id so this query is returning zero and this value is being overwritten in to the object's id field.  The original id is lost which is problematic for the application.

Does anyone know how to overcome this shortfall in Eclipselink with MySQL?

Comment: This is a [known bug in EclipseLink](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323023).  Reported in 2010!  7 years on, I guess I have 2 chances of getting this fixed [Buckley's and Nunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckley_%26_Nunn).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles across this question I did develop a workaround that worked for me.  It's simple in that it just uses JPA listeners to save and restore the lost Id.  Here is my code:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EclipseLinkHistoryFix {

    @Transient
    private Long savedId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @PreUpdate
    public void saveId() {
        savedId = getId();
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void restoreId() {
        if (savedId != null) {
            if (id == null || id.longValue() != savedId.longValue()) {
                setId(savedId);
            }
            savedId = null;
        }
    }

    public final Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public final void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This hack is dependant on the internal behaviour of EclipseLink so may not work in future updates.  Luckily in v2.6.4 the PostUpdate callback is called after the history is inserted so this works great.